# write bytestream to a activex object in javascript

Tags: javascript, activex, activexobject

I am trying to create a file on the local machine which captures the var file in javascript.

```
<script>

function button_click()

{

var file = GetFile('Getdoc'.aspx');

WriteToFile();

}

function WriteToFile() {

    var fso, s;

    fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

    s = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\Test\\Logfile.txt");

    s.Write(file1);

    s.Close();

}

</script>
```

Here we get a httpresponse stream which contains data in bytes into var file.

If I could find some help on this would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are encountering a problem when you are trying to write a file using ActiveXObject on IE? There is two things wrong with your script.

1. `var file = GetFile('Getdoc'.aspx');` should be `var file = GetFile('Getdoc.aspx');`
2. You do not have file1 defined, so it is writing nothing to the file.

You need to keep in mind that most versions of IE have this functionality disabled due to the huge security risk that this poses.

Comment: I am sorry both are typing errors. I made sure both two point you mentioned are updated in the code.

Comment: I just need this for testing purpose on pre-prod to debug the issue, where to find why the same gven file loads on dev but not on pre-prod.